# Bayesian network conditional independency

Tags: statistics, artificial-intelligence, probability, bayesian, bayesian-networks

If we observe that it is cloudy and raining. What is the probability that the grass is wet? The answer would be:

```
P(W=T|C=T,R =T) = P(W=T|R=T,S=T)*P(S=T|C=T)+P(W=T|R=T,S=F)*P(S=F|C=T)
```

But if we observe that the sprinkler is on and the grass is wet, then what would be the probability that it is raining? I'm not sure what would be the solution query to this problem?

[image]

Comment: The presence of the loop makes the problem a little more complex. Maybe you can make progress by conditioning on "Cloudy", which will break the loop.

Comment: @RobertDodier i'm not sure what you mean. Can you please provide an answer?

Comment: Inference in Bayesian networks which are trees (at most one way to get from one variable to another). If there are two or more ways to get from one variable to another, inference is somewhat more complicated. A web search for "Bayesian network loops" will probably turn up some useful links.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>The question is a bit off-topic and better for [math](https://math.stackexchange.com), because formulas aren't supported here...</sup>

1) First, apply the definition of conditional probability:

```
p(R|S,W) = p(R,S,W) / p(S,W)
```

2) The numerator can be computed by the Law of total probability:

```
p(R,S,W) = p(R,S,W|C)p(C) + p(R,S,W|!C)p(!C)
```

and Bayesian network condition:

```
p(R,S,W|C) = p(W|S,R) p(S|C) p(R|C)
```

3) The denominator is computed likewise, but conditioning on both `R` and `C`:

```
p(S,W) = p(S,W|R,C)p(R|C)p(C)   + p(S,W|R,!C)p(R|!C)p(!C) + 
         p(S,W|!R,C)p(!R|C)p(C) + p(S,W|!R,!C)p(!R|!C)p(!C)
```

Finally, each

```
p(S,W|R,C) = p(S,W,R,C) / p(R,C) = 
             p(W|S,R) p(S|C) p(R, C) / p(R,C) = 
             p(W|S,R) p(S|C)
```

This will give you all four: `p(S,W|R,C)`, `p(S,W|R,!C)`, `p(S,W|!R,C)` and `p(S,W|!R,!C)`, which in turn give `p(S,W)`.